# How to centre the background image in a UIView without streching it

Tags: ios, uiview, uiimage, background-image

I want to centre the background image in my `UIView`. The background image is smaller than the `UIView` itself, and I do not want to stretch it, i.e. I want it to have its original size. I wrote the following code

```
UIImage *backgroundImage=[[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:@"analog_display_bgr.png"];

CGSize backgroundImageSize= CGSizeMake (backgroundImage.size.width,backgroundImage.size.height);
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(backgroundImageSize);//self.frame.size
CGRect backgroundImagePosition = CGRectMake(self.bounds.origin.x+m_center.x-backgroundImage.size.width/2.0, self.bounds.origin.y+m_center.y-backgroundImage.size.height/2.0, backgroundImage.size.width, backgroundImage.size.height);
[[UIImage imageNamed:@"analog_display_bgr.png"] drawInRect:backgroundImagePosition];
UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

self.backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithPatternImage:image];
```

I should do the job but does not work.

Any idea what is wrong? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm still not able to replicate the stretching effect you're talking about, but I believe most of your problem lies in this line `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(backgroundImageSize);`. What you want is for the new image to be the size of your view, not the size it already is. Anyway, this code works for me. Let me know if it works for you as well.

```
UIImage *backgroundImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"analog_display_bgr.png"];

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.bounds.size);

CGRect imagePosition = CGRectMake((self.bounds.size.width / 2)  - (backgroundImage.size.width / 2),
                                  (self.bounds.size.height / 2) - (backgroundImage.size.height / 2),
                                  backgroundImage.size.width,
                                  backgroundImage.size.height);

[backgroundImage drawInRect:imagePosition];
UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

self.backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithPatternImage:image];
```

Comment: by streching I mean that the image keeps its original size and is not stretched to the size of the view.

Comment: thanks. your code seems to be correct, but UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.bounds.size); changes the size of the image to the view size.

Answer (score 1):

I tried your code, and I don't get anything at all. Completely blank view. The way I would do what you're describing is like this:

```
UIImage *backgroundImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"analog_display_bgr.png"];
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:backgroundImage];
CGRect imageViewFrame = imageView.frame;
imageViewFrame.origin.x = (self.bounds.size.width / 2) - (imageView.bounds.size.width / 2);
imageViewFrame.origin.y = (self.bounds.size.height / 2) - (imageView.bounds.size.height / 2);
[imageView setFrame:imageViewFrame];
[self addSubview:imageView];
```

I tried it out in `- (void)awakeFromNib` in a UIView subclass and it works fine. Draws the image in the center of the view without stretching it.

If I understand you correctly you want the image to be the background of the view, so behind everything else. The code I provided above will do that, assuming you add the UIImageView behind all the other views. If you still want the image to be drawn as the backgroundColor, like me know and I'll see if I can make it work.

Comment: thanks for your answer. The code centralised the image but does not put the image in the background. Might it be that it really should be drawn as background colour. (In the original code it is the background colour, but not centralised, so I need to change the code). Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for posting yet another answer, but I was not able to add images to a comment, and I want to make sure I completely understand what you want.

So, from what I understand, this is what your code does

[image]

This is what my code does:

[image]

But what you want is something more like this:

[image][image]

Is that correct? If yes, which one? The one to the left or to the right?

Comment: Then I would say I am doing sth wrong somewhere else that I do not see the effect of your code. What I want is exactly what you have shown your code do (from the four images you have shown, I want the one in the second row). Is it the code you posted yesterday? If yes, then that is the answer. Thank you so much for your time.

Comment: @Pegah Yes, that is what the code in my answer (the one that uses a UIGraphicsImageContext) does, at least in my testing. You can easily test it by creating a new project, create a `UIView` subclass, and add the code to `- (void)awakeFromNib` in that subclass. Add a view to your storyboard and set the class. And that's it. You can try out different sizes for the view as well. It should always center the image and keep its size (even if the view is too small or large). I'm happy to help, and I hope you get it working.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `UIImageView` to your `UIView` and set the image to it. You can also play with `UIViewContentMode` property, maybe `UIViewContentModeCenter` or `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill` with `clipToBounds = YES` :)